# Can't change the Case OwnerId to the one I'm passing via the REST API

Tags: rest-api, lightning-experience

I've a case that I want to change the OwnerId (QUEUEIDB) CASE From to another one. The targeted OwnerId is a Queue.
each time I change it with

```
PATCH
https://mycompany.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Case/CASEID
{"OwnerId": "QUEUEIDC"}
```

It seems to work, I get a blank response, but rather than have the case getting the correct QUEUEIDC OwnerID, it changes to QUEUEIDA (which is also a queue).

Why, did you enconter such issue

Comment: By the way, I can change it in the admin web-uii tool

Comment: `OwnerId` is of data type Id, I don't think you can assign a string to an Id.

Comment: What do you mean, of course in my example I didn't put real IDs, it's something like "00G5X000009eIKnUQZ"

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread that :) Do you have any active case assignment rule or anything that might change the owner based on some criteria?

Comment: I think not (I'm not the one that set that up), but when I do it manually in the web GUI of salesforces, I can change it without issue, and it sticks to the one I changes

Comment: does the REST API user have transfer records permission?  The web UI will not execute assignment rules but the REST API may execute assignment rules if the header includes such specification

Comment: Hi, I don't know if it has transfer records permission, how to check for this ? it's logged as the admin thought. Funny thing is that it does change to a Queue, always the same,  but not the one set. Maybe there's a trigger that goes if it's done via Rest that does not apply if that's manually !?